# How to check spreadsheet existence without DriveApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I had a primitive validation of spreadsheet existence:

```js
function isSpreadsheetExist(id)
{
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: error]
I was catching a message *'Document < id > is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)'* and all was ok, but now Google changed something and this message avoids the `try..catch` block and thrown out to UI while this code works well:

```js
function isSpreadsheetExist(id)
{
  try {
    throw 'Error';
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: no error]
I can't use `DriveApp` in my project, so are any ways to check a spreadsheet existence?

Comment: ssId should be id in the first function.

Comment: Sorry. This is a typo in the question, in the code it's ok

Comment: I have checked it out and seems to work properly.

Comment: I have checked the code too, and seems to work properly (no error thrown into the UI, the script runs till the end with `Success` as final status). Where are you running the code from? i.e. are you using the "play" button from the Apps Script IDE?

Comment: @carlesgg97, yes, you could see it on screenshots

Comment: @FLighter Seems to be an intermittent issue - if running the function with a parameter such as `1NUDnH8`, it seems to work (returns `false`) - however something like `1NUDnH8JOqUE81Z70lB0o9yFHvNRdHSbV5XESf4m` raises the exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function, at the moment, presents undefined behaviour, so I would avoid using it. If you would like to report a bug/feature request related to it, you may use the Google issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).

As an alternative, if you still don't want to use the Drive advanced service, you can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to manually issue this request - which, in case it returns an exception, you can easily catch it.

Comment: As you said I'll use `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. If a spreadsheet doesn't exist the response HTTP code will be **410**. `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()` could be used for optimization.